# Regex to minimize the repeated <p></p> tags to one <p></p> tag

Tags: regex

Through the code i got the output content as XML.
I have pair or multiple of XML tags as follows:

```
<p>December10</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p> Welcome to this space </p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>Hai, Today is Tuesday</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>This a xml tag</p>
```

I want a regular expression as below requirement:

As above  mentioned i want only one EMPTY pair Tag as `<p></p>`. I do not want the repeated EMPTY indefinite or definite pair tags.

Please help me in this regard to use regular expression to overcome the issue.

Comment: :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html

Comment: In other words, you only want *unique* matches? This is out of the scope of regular expressions. You have to do it manually from code.

What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Oh God, please don't let [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) see you asking this question.

See:  [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) or [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: he is coming! bobince is coming! oh God no! xD

Answer (score 2):

```
 s/(<p><\/p>)+/<p><\/p>/g;
```

this one work for me (meaning == I tested it with your tagsoup).. it is perl/sed syntax, s///g means 's' replace and 'g' global

Answer (score 1):

If this is .NET, you could try something like this:

`Regex.Replace(content, "(<p>\s*</p>\s*?)+","<p></p>")`

Or even better

`Regex.Replace(content, "(<p>\s*</p>\s*?)+","<p/>")`

(Edited to add Gumbo's suggestion)

Comment: Don’t forget the whitespace between the elements.

Comment: @Kobi: Do you mean the shortened tags?

Comment: Yes, I tried it at least on Firefox and Chrome, though didn't play with doc type.

Comment: @Gumbo: that's what the `\s*` is intended for. Is it incorrect?

Comment: You need another `\s*?` after `</p>`. (`?` because we don't want to match the trailing newline).